# Ways To Show Info Related To ListActivity Items (Toast, New Page, etc)

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter, toast

I am working on learning Android programming. I am attempting to build an app that shows a list of items, and when the user clicks on an item, it will display an image of that item, as well as information about it. I'm not sure the best way to present this information. Would using the Toast widget be best? Or TextView? Or, is there another way, like creating a new activity, that makes more sense?

After the user clicks on the list item, and reads the presented info, they should be able to return to the list.

Any advice on next steps is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

A toast is only able to display a small amount of text, for a particular amount of time.

Generally you will want to start a new Activity to show the details of a ListView item.  By default, if you start a new activity the user will be able to return to the previous activity (your list) by clicking the back button.

If you haven't yet, check out the [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) it goes through a very similar problem in detail.

Comment: Hi Mayra...thanks for the response. I'll read through the Notepad tutorial a bit more closely, and see if that helps!